# Can you print API's quota limit in the same program?

Tags: python, list, api, youtube

The piece of code below retrieves comments from a YouTube video.

YouTube's API has a quota limit of `10,000 units`. So is it possible to display the used and the remaining units in the same program?

```
def getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(topCommentId, replies, token): 
    replies_response=youtube.comments().list(part='snippet',
                                               maxResults=100,
                                               parentId=topCommentId,
                                               pageToken=token).execute()

    for item in replies_response['items']:
        replies.append(item['snippet']['textDisplay'])
    if "nextPageToken" in replies_response: 
      return getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(topCommentId, replies, replies_response['nextPageToken'])
    else:
      return replies
      
def get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments=[], token=''):
  totalReplyCount = 0
  replies=[]

  video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet',
                                               videoId=video_id,
                                               pageToken=token).execute()
  for item in video_response['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']
            text = comment['snippet']['textDisplay']
            totalReplyCount = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
            if (totalReplyCount > 0): 
               comments.extend(getAllTopLevelCommentReplies(comment['id'], replies, None)) 
            else: 
               comments.append(text)
            replies = []

  if "nextPageToken" in video_response: 
        return get_comments(youtube, video_id, comments, video_response['nextPageToken'])
  else:
        return comments

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',developerKey=api_key)
comments = get_comments(youtube,video_id)
print(len(comments))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Youtube's API reference https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs there's no way to retrieve the remaining quota using the API itself.

But you can find out your daily quota usage and limit in your Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).